# Referring to an alias later in the query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, case

I am new to SQL. I want to extract the hour from the timestamp started_at and use it to determine if that time is morning or not. The problem is that I get Unrecognized name: hour at [4:10]. I am not sure how to fix this.

```
SELECT
EXTRACT(HOUR FROM started_at) AS hour,
  CASE 
    WHEN hour between 5 and 9 then "Early Morning"
        else Not Morning"
  END
  FROM `coursera-practice-356200.Cyclistic_data.metered_cyclistic_table`
```

I read that you cannot use an alias later in the query unless you use Order By, but I'm not sure why. I read that to do what I am trying to do is to use a subquery, but I do not know where to begin in that situation. Please Help!

Comment: Use `WHEN EXTRACT(HOUR FROM started_at) BETWEEN 5 AND 9 THEN ...`  instead since you can't use a column alias in the same select list.

Answer (score 0):

First thing first, you have a missing ' right before Not Morning. By alias i guess you want to have the case value on another piece of query within this query ?

If so, i strongly recommend to use CTE the following way:

**Notice the casevalue alias**

```
WITH
  cte AS (
   EXTRACT(HOUR FROM started_at) AS starthour,
  CASE 
    WHEN hour between 5 and 9 then "Early Morning"
    else "Not Morning"
  END AS casevalue
FROM `coursera-practice-356200.Cyclistic_data.metered_cyclistic_table`
  )
SELECT starthour,casevalue
FROM cte;
```

Comment: You seem to forget `SELECT` keyword in the beginning of `cte` and this query won't work since `hour` is supposed to be an alias of calculated column like in PO's question.  You should move `CASE` statement to the main query if you want to use CTE.

Comment: Thank you both so much! The query worked after I used both of your input.

Comment: feel free to mark it as a response and add any tweak :)